# "It has been so long" expression

Tags: expressions

**"It has been so long since i have slept."**

How can I understand ?

"I have slept" is present

I don't understand it...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Right you are! *have slept* is present perfect.

Answer (score 1):

As Lawrence said, *have slept* is [present perfect](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/), which is always made with the appropriate conjugation of *to have* and the past participle of a verb, in this case *slept*. The present perfect refers to something that happened in the past, but is still happening. This is why we call it *present* perfect. I think this is where your misunderstanding began.

So, in this context, the speaker is saying that the last time he slept was a long time ago.

Comment: Oops, sorry to have misled you - it's *present* perfect.

Comment: And that's what I get for trusting my knowledge of grammar terms learned in German... That being said, those two forms are so similar I actually didn't realize they were in fact separate.